# My male leopard gecko will not breed with my female

Tags: breeding, leopard-geckos

My male leopard gecko has been shaking his tail for like 1 second then giving up. It's always been my dream to breed leopard geckos so if someone can help me that would be amazing. I should've added more details. I introduced them about a two weeks ago. They both are of sexual maturity. He is a strain of albino what most people call chocolate albino. And she is a white and yellow possible giant Mack snow.

Comment: How much experience do you have with geckos in general? Did you do any reading on the internet about breeding geckos? What did you find? What do you think that goes wrong in your situation? Please use the "Edit" button and add that information to the question. After that, we might be able to help. Additionally, it will be helpful if you provide a picture with their environment, as well as information about their environment: size, temperature, devices (heater, lights, water cascade...)